# Pyramid on Jython Installation Problems

Tags: python, jython, pyramid, jython-2.5

I am attempting to write an app in Jython running on Pyramid (debating using Django instead right now also). [In the Pyramid Installation Docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/install.html) they mention that they support Python 2.6 and it *has worked* on Jython 2.5.1. Fair enough!

What I don't understand is that Jython 2.5.x is built against the reference Python version of 2.5 which is obviously lesser than the required Python 2.6 version. Thus, when I attempted to install with version even version 2.5.2 of Jython, I get an error when installing from setup-tools `Pyramid requires at least Python 2.6` or something to that effect.

Has anyone attempted this and run into this issue, am I missing something?
Less importantly, why would Pyramid support Python 2.6 but say it *will run* on Jython 2.5 (= Python 2.5)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS - I tried this with the 2.7a builds of Jython and got *passed* the above issue but ended up failing during `c\jython>jython easy_install pyramid` with: `File "C:\jython2.7a2\Lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1441, in auto_chmod IndexError: index out of range: 1`

Comment: Thanks for the ps.  I think 2.7a2 should have worked but I am seeing it not setup the sys.path correctly.  If I can verify the issue I will submit the but and update there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyramid 1.3.X won't run on Jython 2.5.X (or any other Python 2.5-derived implementation) but Pyramid 1.2.X will, as long as you use Python 2.5 compatible versions of its dependencies.  This means WebOb less than 1.2, at least.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I suppose I should just check out the 1.2 branch from github if I want to continue on this path?

Comment: easy_install pyramid<=1.2.99 should get you part of the way; you may then need to install older versions of dependencies that no longer run under python 2.5